# Parameterizing an Array of Ints into SQL Variables in an XQuery Expression

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

We store section IDs (ints) in XML in a column and use XQuery to find items with the specified section IDs. I'm trying to expand the code (in C#) to be able to use an array of ints that are sections IDs. The code works fine in SSMS when the values are hard-coded. When I try to use sql:variable in XQuery, I get no results.

```
declare @table table
(
  Sections nvarchar(200)
)

insert into @table values ('<sections><section value="1" /></sections>')
insert into @table values ('<sections><section value="2" /></sections>')

--This works
select * from @table where CONVERT(xml, Sections).exist('/sections/section[@value = (1,2)]') = 1

--This doesn't work :(
Declare @stringvalue nvarchar(50)
set @stringvalue = '(1,2)'
select * from @table where CONVERT(xml, Sections).exist('/sections/section[@value = sql:variable("@stringvalue")]') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable is of type `@stringvalue` the expression evaluates to this:

```
.exist('/sections/section[@value = "(1,2)"]')
```

This matches on the string value `"(1,2)"`, not the actual sequence. Declare the variable to be `xml` data type. When you evaluate it, it should return a sequence instead of the string representation.

Comment: I think you're right about the string and quotes. The problem must lie with data types. Still can't quite figure it out though. I tried "Declare @stringvalue xml" and got this error: "XQuery [exist()]: An XML instance is only supported as the direct source of an insert using sql:column/sql:variable." I appreciate the help!

Comment: Since there aren't proper sequences in SQL, you could try storing the values in a column an evaluating that. Or you could just start with an XML data type and turn it into a sequence in xpath: `<sequence><value>1</value><value>2</value></sequence>` => `[@value = sql:variable("@newxmlvalue")/value/string()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with dynamic SQL but it's a bit hacky, eg:

```
create table #table 
(
  Sections nvarchar(200)
)

insert into #table values ('<sections><section value="1" /></sections>')
insert into #table values ('<sections><section value="2" /></sections>')

Declare @stringvalue nvarchar(50)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @stringvalue = '(1,2)'

set @sql = 'select * from #table where CONVERT(xml, Sections).exist(''/sections/section[@value = ' + @stringvalue + ']'') = 1'
exec(@sql)
```